# Filtering REST query by multiple boolean conditions

Tags: search, api

I am trying convert this pseudo sql query to search api

```
SELECT * FROM Sites WHERE Path IN ("www.xyz.xx","www.zys.xx") AND Type = "STS_Web"
```

Basically I just want to return info about sites by given paths.
This what I have tried so far, but it does not work.

```
(path:https://www.xyz.xx/forum/101/100 OR path:https://www.xyz.xx/forum/100/100) AND contentclass:STS_Web

/_api/search/query?querytext='(path:https:%2f%2fportal.xxx.com:443%2fforum%2f101%2f100+OR+path:https:%2f%2fportal.xxx.com:443%2fforum%2f100%2f100)+AND+contentclass:STS_Web'&trimduplicates=true&enablequeryrules=false&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'
```

Comment: Are you looking for confirmation? Is your query not working? Not entirely sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='(path=https://portal.xxx.com:443/forum/101/100 OR path=https://portal.xxx.com:443/forum/100100) AND contentclass=STS_Web'&trimduplicates=true&enablequeryrules=false&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'
```